# Google App Script How to view user properties for all users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Using the app script properties service I can allow users to store some settings information. I understand that these are stored for a given user for a given script. As the admin is there anyway for me to review all the users properties?

Also does anyone know if you are allowing the script to run as you (the publisher) does the user properties store as the user accessing the script. I know that the session data is for the actual user and not the publishing user(even when running as the publishing user).

Thanks

Comment: Some of your questions are answered on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service).

Comment: the rest of your questions are answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Comment: I understand how to get the user attributes for the current user on the script. I want to know if there is a way to view all user settings for all users that have used the script the documentation does not explain that. @ Antoine Colson what part of the post answers the question about user settings? I read through but I must be missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest storing the user properties in Firebase. This will give you full access to them as needed, and they load really fast for the user. My two go to docs for this are this one to get [the library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) and this one to as for [details.](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script) If this is not possible, an alternative could be to append a row to a google sheet each time the user updates their users properties. I use both of these approaches for also tracking detailed app usages.